# How To Select specific column As Row?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables Phone_record and customer

In my phone records tables I have two columns company_name and ModelNo 
Now I want to show  Company_name as my main column name 
And in this column I want to show models of that company like this

```
Company 1                  company2..... 
Model1                     model1
Model2                     model2
```

How to write this query?

Comment: Can you please post sample data, expected results *and* what you've tried. (None of these should be images, post it as formatted `text`)

Comment: Please follow these recommendations when asking SQL questions. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sounds to me like a typical dynamic cross tab.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully functional example of how you might do this.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    ID int,
    Subject1 varchar(50)
)

insert #Something
select 10868952, 'Some Subject' union all
select 10868952, 'Another one' union all
select 10868952, 'This Subject' union all
select 10868952, 'Science' union all
select 12345, 'My Subject'
declare @MaxCols int

declare @StaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = 
    'with OrderedResults as
    (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID order by Subject1) as RowNum
        from #Something
    )
    select ID';

declare @DynamicPortion nvarchar(max) = '';
declare @FinalStaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = ' from OrderedResults Group by ID order by ID';

with E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --100 rows
cteTally(N) AS 
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2
)

select @DynamicPortion = @DynamicPortion + 
    ', MAX(Case when RowNum = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then Subject1 end) as Subject' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + CHAR(10)
from cteTally t
where t.N <= 
(
    select top 1 Count(*)
    from #Something
    group by ID
    order by COUNT(*) desc
)

--select @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion

declare @SqlToExecute nvarchar(max) = @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion;
exec sp_executesql @SqlToExecute
```